# Keep a single Entities object or use a new one every time

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

well the thing is this:

I'm using a Visual Studio generated Entity Data Model and I would like to know if it would be more efficient (in memory use matters) to keep a single Entity Context object to use in all my application and dispose it when closing the app or create a new one every time I need to access data and dispose it after?

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on the assumption that you are talking about the Entity Context. Standard practice is to dispose of the object when you are done using it. That's because it can use lots of memory as well as hold one or more DB connections open.

Comment: you assumed right! Sorry the incoherence on the question, edited to be more clear, and thanks for your answer, and what you said makes perfect sense, still some coworkers thinks keeping a single object would be more efficient, investigation in progress....

Comment: It depends on your use case. It takes very little time to create a context. Typically you want to dispose of the context as soon as you can to free up database resources. For example, our web application creates a Context for each HTTP request and disposes of it at the end of the request. If we kept it for the entire session, we would very quickly run out of available DB connections.